# How can we capture and save in local disk with Aforge video?

Tags: c#, video-capture, aforge

I want to save video which capturing from webcam into local disk. I wrote code it shows webcam but It can't save into local disk. The error is **Failed creating compressed stream.**. What should I do in here?

```
            writer = new AVIWriter("wmv3");
            writer.FrameRate = 30;
            writer.Open("video.avi", Convert.ToInt32(640), Convert.ToInt32(480)); // ERROR İS HERE **Failed creating compressed stream.**

            //Create NewFrame event handler
            //(This one triggers every time a new frame/image is captured
            videoSource.NewFrame += new AForge.Video.NewFrameEventHandler(videoSource_NewFrame);

            //Start recording
            videoSource.Start();


        }
    }       
    void videoSource_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {

        //Cast the frame as Bitmap object and don't forget to use ".Clone()" otherwise
        //you'll probably get access violation exceptions
        pictureBoxVideo.BackgroundImage = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        writer.AddFrame((Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone());
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a WMV3 encoder installed on your computer? I may be mistaken, but you should consider downloading and installing the Microsoft Expression Encoder from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/#encoder).

Comment: I installed but how I encode Microsoft Expression Encoder with Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever consider the size of the stream of your webcam?  I have the same problem, too.  I know you set your video size into 640 and 480, but the video stream size which comes from your webcam(I guess) would be never the same.  I also guess you set your container such as picturebox or imagebox into 640 and 480, but that doesn't mean the video stream would be the same.  I use savedialog to check the video stream that comes out of my webcam, and guess what?  The size would be (648, 486).  Who would ever set such a strange number set? But I set my code into this :

> writer.Open("video.avi", Convert.ToInt32(648), Convert.ToInt32(486));

And it works fine!

I do not know the rest of your code is correct or not, but I'm sure my bug is in the set of size :)

Answer (score 0):

Four years later I'm having this same issue. After hours I figured out if I didn't specify `wmv3` for the codec and just left it blank `writer = new AVIWriter();` then everything worked.

```
AVIWriter write = new AVIWriter();
write.Open("newTestVideo.avi", Convert.ToInt32(320), Convert.ToInt32(240));
Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(320, 240);
for (int tt = 0; tt < 240; tt++) {
    bit.SetPixel(tt, tt, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb((int)(UnityEngine.Random.value * 255f), (int)(UnityEngine.Random.value * 255f), (int)(UnityEngine.Random.value * 255f)));
    write.AddFrame(bit);
}
write.Close();
```